# Are the loops in python similar to matlab?

Tags: python, for-loop, arcmap

I'm new in using Python - Arcmap.

I have on my map a list of layers with the nearly same name (bound3 to bound50)

I want to calculate the MinimumBoundingGeometry_management. I found out how to do it for one single layer.

`arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management("bound3","bound3ConvexHull","CONVEX_HULL","ALL")`

Instead I'd like to create a loop like in matlab style:

`for i=3:1:50
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(boundi,boundiConvexHull,...
"CONVEX_HULL","ALL")
end`

can someone give me an hint !

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to construct the strings `"boundi"` and `"boundiConvexHull"` for each i.

Instead of `3:50` (in Matlab) you do `xrange(3,51)` in python. The reason you go up to `51` is that `xrange(n)` generates the sequence `0:(n-1)` (python is 0-based whereas matlab is 1-based).

```
for i in xrange(3,51):
    arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management("bound%i" % i, "bound%iConvexHull" % i, ... )
```

I've made use of python's string formatting: `"bound%i" % i` is syntactic sugar for printf-type functions that you are familiar with in matlab.

Handy links:

- [Python for loops.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html)
- [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange)
- [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) ("apples x %i, $%s" % (2,1.50) --> "apples x 2, $1.50")